# Application Insights Analytics multiple events in same session

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Pretty new to AI queries so any help will be much appreciated.

We have a host of custom events for particular actions for example, booking appointments, ordering products, setting an address. I would like to run a query to look at users who performed both ordering a product and setting their address in the same session. I can get a count and dcount of either events happening but struggling to specify that both happen in the same session We capture the User_authID as well session id with the custom events. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You have to tell us a bit more. How/where are the session id and user_authID stored, in the customDimensions? How does a simple query output look like (so we get a better view of what is stored where)

Comment: Hi Peter, they are not stored in the custom dimensions. When I run the query, the setting address is captured as name: setAddress. Along with this, the sessionID and UserID is captured. So something like                                    name:setAddress  sessionID:123   UserID: 456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. I find using the `in` operator and a subquery to be the easiest to read. Here's an example that does it:

```
let timeRange = ago(1d);
let sessionsWithBothEvents = customEvents
| where timestamp > timeRange
| summarize CountEvent1=countif(name == "event1"), CountEvent2=countif(name == "event2") by session_Id
| where CountEvent1 > 0 and CountEvent2 > 0
| project session_Id;
customEvents
| where timestamp > timeRange
| where session_Id in (sessionsWithBothEvents)
// Here you have all the events in sessions that contained at least one instance of each event
// From here you can dcount users, etc.
```

It is important to note that this approach will only work for up to 1 million session ids that match the criteria. This is due to the limitations of the `in` operator. See https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Scalar-operators/in_!in-operators for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will be querying over 10 Million session IDs, are there any other approaches that would be better for this case?

Comment: Just for clarity, it's fine if the total number of session IDs in your telemetry is > 1M, your filter criteria (eg. sessions with event1 and event2) must match <= 1M. Depending on what exactly you're trying to get out of these sessions, you can remove the second query (and the limited `in` operator altogether). For example, you can simply count within the `sessionsWithBothEvents` query to get the number of sessions/users who met the criteria.